# How to convert a list of Buttons into an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, button

I'm looking to make a two-dimensional array of buttons. I've named the b1, b2, b3, b4 (b5 will be on next line etc).
I can add the buttons to a one-dimensional list, as shown below:

```
List<Button> buttonList;

buttonList = new List<Button> {b1,b2,b3,b4,b5 (etc.)};
```

Now, I need to put these buttons into an array that is kind of like this:

```
{{0, 1, 2 , 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11}, {12, 13, 14, 15}};
```

where `b1` will be 0, `b2` will be 1 and so on and so forth.

I'm quite new to this and can't find anything that is similar, I'm not too good with for/foreach loops and maybe one of these was needed to do this, so how can I do this?

Comment: *i'm not too good with for/foreach loop* - so why don't you try to learn more about them first, instead of hoping for us to do your work?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArray = new Button[,] { { b1, b2, b3, b4 },
                              { b5, b6, b7, b8 },
                              { b9, b10, b11, b12 },
                              { b13, b14, b15, b16 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somethinhg like this:

```
var lst = new List<List<Button>>();
lst.Add(new List<Button>{b1,b2,b3});
lst.Add(new List<Button>{b4,b5,b6});

foreach(var buttonList in lst)
{
  foreach(var button in buttonList )
  {
    //do stuff with button
  }
}
```

Or if you need the colection to be array (for thatever reason)

```
var ary = List<Button>[2]; //two elements in ary.
ary[0] = new List<Button>{b1,b2,b3};
ary[1] = new List<Button>{b4,b5,b6};
```

the loop remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
   var x = new List<List<Button>>
                    {
                        new List<Button>
                            {

                             b4,b5,b6

                            }
                    };
```

or use

```
      var x=  new Button[] { { b1, b2, b3, b4 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a list of lists instead of an array.

```
var groupedList = new List<List<Button>>();

for(i = 0; i < buttonList.length / 4 + 1; i++) //plus one will ensure we don't loose buttons if their number doesn't divide on four
{
   groupedList.Add(buttonList.Skip(i * 4).Take(4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to update your `List<Button>` with `int [][]`

```
var nums = new[] { new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 }, new[] { 8, 9, 10, 11 }, new[] { 12, 13, 14, 15 } };
int counter = 0;
foreach (int[] ints in nums)
{
    foreach (int i in ints)
    {
        buttonList[counter].Text = i.ToString();
        counter++;
    }
}
```

A better way to approach this can be :

```
private List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();
private void addButtonsDynamically(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int top = 10, left = 10;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Parent = this;
        btn.Size = new Size(25, 25);
        btn.Text = (i - 1).ToString();
        btn.Location = new Point(left, top);

        left += 35;
        if (i > 0 && i % 4 == 0)
        {
            top += 35;
            left = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

it will create a output like :

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your list to an array (4 in a row) here is a LINQ way to do this:

```
var buttonsArray = buttonsList
                   .Select((b, i) => new {Index = i, Button = b})
                   .GroupBy(x => x.Index/4)
                   .Select(x=>x.Select(y=>y.Button).ToArray())
                   .ToArray();
```